# What does domain mean in the OOP?

Tags: oop

I read a book by OOP. And it uses `domain` term frequently but I can't get clearly what is it in OOP. Is it a namespace?
I found a description for the domain model but I don't sure that is same.
Can a someone explain, pls?
**P.S.** Book explains OOP paradigmas so it doesn't relate to the Internet terms.

[Link to the book](http://agp1.hx0.ru/articles/typeSetsClasses.pdf)

Comment: Care the share the name of the book, and author?

Comment: @R.Richards, I don't sure that it helps( It is in Russian, unfortunately.

Comment: Got it. Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(software_engineering).

Comment: @R.Richards, just it means also the group of objects or a set of values of a some type. So, I asked to know its meaning in the OOP relation.

Comment: In my exam that for I read it. It asks "Objects, classes, domains and relations between them".

Comment: Good question. Without the full context, that could be difficult to answer. Here domain could encompass the *common requirements, terminology, and functionality*, which could help you to draw conclusions about relationships.

Comment: I see( But in any case thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have an ice cream van. Your domain named **entity** will contain your ice cream interface and different kinds of ice cream classes.

And suppose you're keeping track of sold ice cream with help of your notebook. That will be your DB **domain**. In OOP languages like Java you'll have something like dao domain or repository domain, depending on what kind of design pattern you prefer most.

At last, you have yourself, kind of connecting ice cream with your customers. The interface if Ice cream guy and particularly your implementation will lie in something like connector domain.

**UPD**. Well, you should think towards domain driven design. You put all models, entities in one package and call it **model**, you can have multiple different interfaces/abstractions and their implementations there, it's not about having a single one, and that's your model domain. You create **service** package in your root folder and create an operating class to your models - that's your **service** domain. You create an **action** domain to operate with methods of services created previously - and that's your new **action** domain.

Comment: This is a little less philosophical than my comment, and speaks more to the point of domains in specific scopes. Likely, a much better answer on an exam. Well done!

Comment: Thank you for answer! Sorry, my English isn't good. I.e. is the domain an abstraction (interface) of a some class set?

Comment: Answer updated. I recommend you to refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325836/what-is-domain-driven-design) on DDD. You can also find this explained on habrahabr (specially for you).

Answer (score 1):

domain in OOP programming terms, simply means where your Data-end and Presentation-end connect together .in Clean architecture pattern this is where you define your repository/entities/use cases and connect repository to data-repository and entities to models on Data-end of your pattern and use cases to your state management pattern .

I hope this answer help you to understand this concept in OOP .